# SQL: enumerate returned rows within each group

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a `SELECT ...` query that returns sth. like this:

```
role      name
--------  -------
MANAGER   Alice
WORKER    Bob
WORKER    Evan
WORKER    John
MANAGER   Max
WORKER    Steve
```

Is it possible to add another column that enumerates rows within each group (i.e. managers, workers and people on any other role are enumerated with no regard to other roles)? Like this:

```
role      name     no.
--------  -------  ----
MANAGER   Alice     1
WORKER    Bob       1        // second row, but the first worker
WORKER    Evan      2
WORKER    John      3
MANAGER   Max       2        // fifth row, but only the second manager
WORKER    Steve     4
```

Usage of Oracle extensions is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
select role, name, 
       row_number() over (partition by role order by name) as rn
from the_table
order by name;
```