# enumerating rows in sql with multiple same values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I want to enumerate rows such that non-unique values get the same number and do not increase. So my data should look like:

```
id - term_seq_id - rn
---------------------
1    0944          1
1    0944          1
1    0962          2
2    1024          1
2    1054          2
```

I was looking at this solution:

[SQL: enumerate returned rows within each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37968293/sql-enumerate-returned-rows-within-each-group)

Which works if the values are all unique in the `ORDER BY` statement in the window function. So I have the following query from this solution but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT  student_id_fk
, Term_Seq_Id
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id_fk ORDER BY Term_Seq_Id ) AS rn
FROM Courses AS c

ORDER BY student_id_fk, Term_Seq_Id
```

However this fails to provide the correct output. Instead it does:

```
id - term_seq_id - rn
---------------------
1    0944          1
1    0944          2
1    0962          3
2    1024          1
2    1054          2
```

I am at a loss, there doesn't seem to be any way to say "only increment if `term_seq_id` increases". I tried partioning by  multiple rows but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this:

```
SELECT  student_id_fk
, Term_Seq_Id
, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id_fk ORDER BY Term_Seq_Id ) AS rn
FROM Courses AS c

ORDER BY student_id_fk, Term_Seq_Id
```

Answer (score 3):

use `dense_rank()`

```
SELECT  student_id_fk
, Term_Seq_Id
, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id_fk ORDER BY Term_Seq_Id ) AS rn
FROM Courses AS c

ORDER BY student_id_fk, Term_Seq_Id
```