# using dense_rank to find when column changes in time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have [previously used `dense_rank` to enumerate rows with multiples of the same values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215523/enumerating-rows-in-sql-with-multiple-same-values). But now I want to do essentially the same thing, except order by more rows. Basically I have this query:

```
SELECT student_id_fk, Long_Desc, Term_Seq_Id, [semester index]
, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id_fk ORDER BY Long_Desc ASC ) AS [major index]
FROM @semester_index AS si
ORDER BY Term_Seq_Id
```

The ultimate goal of this query is to produce a chronological rank for every time a student changes their major. So when the student changes from math to civil engineering, the `major index` will change from 1 to 2.

However the query as it stands produces this output

```
student_id_fk   Long_Desc   Term_Seq_Id semester index  major index
1234    Mathematics         0934    1   2
1234    Mathematics         0936    2   2
1234    Civil Engineering   0942    3   1
1234    Civil Engineering   0944    4   1
```

But this produces the opposite output I want, because it is ordering by the `Long_Desc` column alphabetically. What I want is it to be ordered chronologically like this:

```
student_id_fk   Long_Desc   Term_Seq_Id semester index  major index
1234    Mathematics         0934    1   1
1234    Mathematics         0936    2   1
1234    Civil Engineering   0942    3   2
1234    Civil Engineering   0944    4   2
```

I am unsure how to order the data in the way that produces the correct ranks.

edit:

What I ended up doing to solve this problem was use [`lag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in combination with `dense_rank`.

Comment: what is the indicator that the student changed his major?

Comment: when `Long_Desc`  changes.

Comment: this is what generated the `major index` column.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?  (Grabbing the max TermSeqId for each major to sort by)

Table:

```
Create Table #semidx
(
studentid_fk Int,
LongDesc VarChar(20),
TermSeqId char(4),
semidx Int
)
Insert Into #semidx Values

(1234,'Mathematics','0934',1),
(1234,'Mathematics','0936',2),
(1234,'Civil Engineering','0942',3),
(1234,'Civil Engineering','0944',4)
```

Query

```
SELECT 
   si.studentid_fk, 
   si.LongDesc, 
   TermSeqId, 
   semidx,
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY si.studentid_fk ORDER BY si.LongDesc Asc ) AS [MajorIndex]
FROM #semidx AS si
Left Join
(
   Select studentid_fk, LongDesc, Max(TermSeqId) As tsi From #semidx
   Group By studentid_fk, LongDesc
)  As m 
   On m.studentid_fk = si.studentid_fk And m.LongDesc = si.LongDesc
   Order By tsi
```

UPDATE: I haven't fully vetted the following, but it seems to be much closer to what I think you're saying.  The following does a dense rank on the difference between Row Numbers by major and the TermSeqId

```
Select 
   studentid_fk,
   LongDesc,
   TermSeqId, 
   Dense_Rank() OVER (Partition By studentid_fk Order By rnk) As majoridx
From 
(
Select *, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TermSeqId) -
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LongDesc ORDER BY TermSeqId) AS rnk
From
#semidx ) t
Order By studentid_fk, t.TermSeqId
```

Comment: This produces the opposite. It should be ordered by the `Term_Seq_Id`. Basically, it works almost exactly the way I want, except that it creates the major index in the wrong direction. so rows earlier in time (lower `term_seq_id`s) have high major indices when they should be lower. So in the data case the first major the student declared is mathematics, then the second major is civil engineering.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I provided a different approach.  Hopefully, it gets you closer to what your needing...

Comment: this works for test data but not real data, im still trying to figure out why.

Answer (score -1):

You have to order your result set by Semister index rather than long_desc.

```
SELECT student_id_fk, Long_Desc, Term_Seq_Id, [semester index]
, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id_fk ORDER BY [semester index] ASC ) AS [major index]
FROM @semester_index AS si
ORDER BY Term_Seq_Id
```

Comment: this doesnt work, it produces the same result as `semester index`